# How do I join a table but filter only that table prior to join and do the same for the other table?

Tags: sql, join, filter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*Apologies for the poor formatting (this is my first post.)*

**I'm working this on Snowflake - SQL (without writing permissions, so I can't alter the data.)**

I want to make a report that will capture monthly fees on one table.

Table 2 will always have matching ID's but occasionally the tables 1,3,4 will not have matching ID's with each other.

In this case:
I want the fees of a certain month "202301" to be on the same table, joining them based on the ID.
TABLE 1,2,4 will join with no issue but the TABLE3 has no matches. How can I filter the bill_month of each table to only include "202301" without impacting the join in the way it currently is?

We have TABLE1 has

| ID | Billing_month | A_FEE | MCC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202301 | 20.00 | 0001 |
| 1 | 202212 | 34.00 | 0001 |
| 2 | 202301 | 51.00 | 2222 |
| 2 | 202211 | 22.00 | 2222 |
| 2 | 202210 | 51.00 | 2222 |
| 3 | 202109 | 22.00 | 3333 |
| 3 | 202301 | 22.00 | 3333 |

We have TABLE2

| ACCT | Rate_Program |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IC |
| 2 | IC |
| 3 | IC |
| 4 | IC |
| 5 | SFNF |

We have TABLE3

| ID | Billing_month | B_FEE | MCC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 202301 | 10.00 | 1111 |
| 4 | 202212 | 24.00 | 1111 |
| 2 | 202201 | 21.00 | 2222 |
| 2 | 202211 | 42.00 | 2222 |
| 2 | 202210 | 21.00 | 2222 |
| 3 | 202109 | 32.00 | 3333 |
| 3 | 202201 | 42.00 | 3333 |

We have TABLE4: A unique fee

| ID | Billing_month | C_FEE | MCC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202301 | 15.00 | 0001 |
| 1 | 202212 | 34.00 | 0001 |
| 2 | 202301 | 51.00 | 2222 |
| 2 | 202211 | 22.00 | 2222 |
| 2 | 202210 | 54.00 | 2222 |
| 3 | 202109 | 22.00 | 3333 |
| 3 | 202301 | 24.00 | 3333 |

I would prefer to not use a NOT statement as there are too many billing_month values to add. And I thought by including the conditional clause of billing_month = '202301' would allow me to get my wanted output but I was wrong. I'm fairly new to SQL so hopefully some input would help! Thanks.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.acct and t1.billing_month = '202301'
FULL JOIN TABLE3 t3
    ON t3.ID, = t2.acct and t3.billing_month = '202301'
FULL JOIN TABLE4 t4
    ON t4.ID, = t2.acct and t4.billing_month = '202301'
    where t1.MCC not in ('4444','5555')
        and t2.rate_program not in ('SFNF', 'SPSF', 'SF')
```

Real Output

| ID | Billing_month | A_FEE | B_FEE | C_FEE | MCC | Rate_Program |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202301 | 20.00 |  | 15.00 | 0001 | IC |
| 2 | 202301 | 51.00 |  | 54.00 | 2222 | IC |
| 3 | 202301 | 22.00 |  | 24.00 | 3333 | IC |

Wanted Output

| ID | Billing_month | A_FEE | B_FEE | C_FEE | MCC | Rate_Program |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202301 | 20.00 |  | 15.00 | 0001 | IC |
| 2 | 202301 | 51.00 |  | 54.00 | 2222 | IC |
| 3 | 202301 | 22.00 |  | 24.00 | 3333 | IC |
| 4 | 202301 |  | 10.00 |  | 1111 | IC |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4th row is missing in your query output because of possibility of null value in t1.MCC, t2.rate_program columns.

So you would have to add an additional condition to check for NULL values before checking the not in condition:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.acct and t1.billing_month = '202301'
FULL JOIN TABLE3 t3
    ON t3.ID = t2.acct and t3.billing_month = '202301'
FULL JOIN TABLE4 t4
    ON t4.ID = t2.acct and t4.billing_month = '202301'
where (t1.MCC is null or t1.MCC not in ('4444','5555'))
    and (t2.rate_program is null or t2.rate_program not in ('SFNF', 'SPSF', 'SF') )       
;
```

---

while combining the ID columns in the select clause of the query, you can use like below:

```
SELECT IFNULL(t1.id,IFNULL(t2.acct,IFNULL(t3.id,t4.id)))
```

Comment: This worked when I included "and (t1.billing_month is null or t1.billing_month like '202301') and (t3.billing_month is null or t3.billing_month like '202301') and (t4.billing_month is null or t4.billing_month like '202301')" Thank you! It also seems like the t3.ID = t2.acct join did not work correctly.  So, I'll have to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.acct and t1.billing_month = '202301' FULL JOIN TABLE3 t3
ON t3.ID = t2.acct and t3.billing_month = '202301'FULL JOIN TABLE4 t4
ON t4.ID = t2.acct and t4.billing_month = '202301'                           
where (t1.MCC is null or t1.MCC not in ('4444','5555'))
and (t2.rate_program is null or t2.rate_program not in ('SFNF', 'SPSF', 'SF') ) 
and (t1.billing_month is null or t1.billing_month like '202301')   
and (t3.billing_month is null or t3.billing_month like '202301') 
and (t4.billing_month is null or t4.billing_month like '202301')
```

This seems to have worked (expanding on what @Uma Deivasigamani suggested.)

The issue that I currently am running into is this now

| ID | Billing_month | A_FEE | B_FEE | C_FEE | MCC | Rate_Program |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202301 | 20.00 |  | 15.00 | 0001 | IC |
| 2 | 202301 | 51.00 |  | 54.00 | 2222 | IC |
| 3 | 202301 | 22.00 |  | 24.00 | 3333 | IC |
|  |  |  | 10.00 |  |  |  |

We get the fee but the Joined ID column is returning null even though there is a match.